# jmeter stress/break point performance test using constant throughput timer

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, stress-testing, beanshell

IN JMETER , 
How can we change the constant throughput timer value Using a ( JavaScript or Bean Shell) function ?
Say for example, test duration is 60 mins . constant throughput timer initially set to 4000 samples per min then hold the load for 5 mins.  After 5 mins , it should increment and set to 5000 samples per min then hold the load for 5 mins . after 5 mins , it should increment to 6000 samples per min. 
any ideas welcome.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe better option would be using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project

The relevant configuration would be something like:

[image: JMeter Throughput Shaping Timer]

Also it is possible to set so called [Load Profiles](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) using `load_profile` JMeter Property.

---

You can install Throughput Shaping Timer plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Throughput Shaping Timer]

Comment: Thanks for throughput shaping timer. it would be good if you explain load profile "Also it is possible to set so called Load Profiles using load_profile JMeter Property." and also i came to know that constant throughput timer can be controlled via beanshell . "http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server" something like this.. do you have any idea on it???